# Pandas groupby dataframe then return single value result (sum, total)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Dears,

Please help me, I am stucked.I guess it should not be difficult but I feel overwhelmed.

Need to make ageing of receivables, therefore they must be separated in different buckets.

Suppose we have only 3 groups: **current**, **above_10Days** and **above_20Days** and the following table:

```
d = {'Cust': [Dfg, Ers, Dac, Vds, Mhf, Kld, Xsd, Hun], 
'Amount': [10000, 100000, 4000, 5411, 756000, 524058, 4444785, 54788,
'Days': 150, 21, 30, 231, 48, 15, -4, -14 }
```

[image]

I need to group the amounts to a total sum, depending on the Ageing group.
Example:
Current: 4499573, etc.

For that purpose, I tried to group the receivables with such code:

```
 above_10Days = df.groupby((df['Days'] > 0) & (df['Days'] <= 10))
 above10sum = above_10Days.Amount.sum().iloc[1]
```

It works perfect but only when they are actual amount in this group.
When they are no such A/R it throws an exception and stop executing. I tried to use function or to make 'None' value to 0, but no success.

Hopefully someone could know the solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I lost you at `Example: Current: 4499573, etc.` Please can you explain clearly what you are looking to achieve. For example, show us your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and excuse me for vague explanation. My desired output would be three groups: Current,  above_10Days and above_20Days containing the totals(sum) of the respective amounts. Ex: Current: 4499573, below_10Days: 0, above_20Days: 875411 etc. Hopefully, now is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
d = {'Cust': ['Dfg', 'Ers', 'Dac', 'Vds', 'Mhf', 'Kld', 'Xsd', 'Hun'], 
'Amount': [10000, 100000, 4000, 5411, 756000, 524058, 4444785, 54788],
'Days': [150, 21, 30, 231, 48, 15, -4, -14] }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

#Updated to assign to output dataframe
df_out = (df.groupby(pd.cut(df.Days,
                  [-np.inf,10,20,np.inf],
                  labels=['Current','Above 10 Days','Above 20 Days']))['Amount']
  .sum())
```

Output:

```
Days
Current          4499573
Above 10 Days     524058
Above 20 Days     875411
Name: Amount, dtype: int64
```

Varible assignent using `.loc`:

```
varCurrent = df_out.loc['Current']
var10 = df_out.loc['Above 10 Days']
var20 = df_out.loc['Above 20 Days']
print(varCurrent,var10,var20)
```

Output:

```
4499573 524058 875411
```

Comment: Huge thanks, Scott! That is exactly what I need. Do not want to bother you further, but I blocked. Please advice can I assign the totals in Current, Above 10 Days.. etc to variables, that can be further manipulated. For instance a = 4499573, b = 524058, c = 875411. I must confess that I have so much to learn for pandas data manipulation

Comment: You can use different labels in the above statement instead of 'Current' just use 'a'.  I not complete clear on you desired output.

Comment: Please, excuse me for the ambiguous explanation. What I mean is that DataFrame which summarizes result is perfectly fine but can I split the DataFrame rows to a single variables. For example varCurrent = 4499573, var10 = 524058. I need them as variables for further data manipulation.....just reading documentation regarding loc, iloc and ix and some other library methods.

Comment: Ah.. you are on the right trrack.  Use .loc don't use .ix that is old deprecated functionality.